# Find element by id and append in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to figure out a way of doing this. This is my object:

```
    {
   "id":1,
   "name":"Blooper Corp.",
   "emoji":"",
   "parent_id":null,
   "children":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Food",
         "emoji":"",
         "parent_id":1,
         "children":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"Canine Therapy",
         "emoji":"",
         "parent_id":1,
         "children":[
            {
               "id":4,
               "name":"Massages",
               "emoji":"",
               "parent_id":3,
               "children":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "id":5,
               "name":"Games",
               "emoji":"",
               "parent_id":3,
               "children":[

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the last `id` of the array so I can use it in the new child array and add it as a child to that specific tier, for example:

```
{
  "id":6, // New id
  "name":"Music",
  "emoji":"",
  "parent_id":4, //this will be the parent id it belongs to
  "children":[

  ]
}
```

This is my javascript button function:

```
function askUserForTeamDetails( team ) {
    const emoji = prompt( 'Enter new team’s emoji:' );
    if ( null === emoji ) {
        return;
    }
    const name = prompt( 'Enter new team’s name:' );
    if ( null === name ) {
        return;
    }
    let tree = getTree();
    tree.id = {}; //new child array to push depending on parent id

    return { name, emoji };
}
```

`getTree()`:

```
const tree = {"id":1,"name":"Rusty Corp.","emoji":"","parent_id":null,"children":[{"id":2,"name":"Food","emoji":"","parent_id":1,"children":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Canine Therapy","emoji":"","parent_id":1,"children":[{"id":4,"name":"Massages","emoji":"","parent_id":3,"children":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Games","emoji":"","parent_id":3,"children":[]}]}]};
return tree;
```

I've tried using `Object.keys(tree)[Object.keys(tree).length-1];` But I don't see how this will work since it's multidimensional.

I hope someone can advise a way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the getTree() function you're calling?

Comment: @nixkuroi it is just fetching the JSON from a global javascript variable. I have added it in.

Comment: If the last id is 5 why is `"parent_id"` 4 in that new object?

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag, especially the part in CAPS.

Comment: @NenadVracar the `parent_id` can be the parent id it belongs to. There id 6 is a child of 4 in the example.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are referring to @trincot please can you explain.

Comment: Is the result of `getTree()` supposed to be an array? Because right now it's an object and you can't use `push` on an object. Also how do you identify if a new team is a child of another? There's no option to add it as a child.

Comment: @designtocode the JSON tag is not appropriate for javascript object literals, which is the only "JSON" in your question. I have removed it from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add new object based on `parent_id` property that can be on any level, you can create recursive function that will traverse the object with `for...in` loop and push the object to children if the id matches.

```js
const data = {"id":1,"name":"Blooper Corp.","emoji":"","parent_id":null,"children":[{"id":2,"name":"Food","emoji":"","parent_id":1,"children":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Canine Therapy","emoji":"","parent_id":1,"children":[{"id":4,"name":"Massages","emoji":"","parent_id":3,"children":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Games","emoji":"","parent_id":3,"children":[]}]}]}

function insert(data, obj, pid = null) {
  if (pid == obj.parent_id) {
    data.children.push(obj);
    return;
  }

  if (data.children) {
    data.children.forEach(e => insert(e, obj, e.id))
  }
}

function getLastId(data) {
  let result = null;

  function search(data) {
    if (!result || data.id > result) result = data.id;
    if (data.children)  data.children.forEach(search);
  }

  search(data);
  return result;
}

const newObj = {
  "id": getLastId(data) + 1,
  "name": "Music",
  "emoji": "",
  "parent_id": 4,
  "children": []
}

insert(data, newObj);
console.log(data)
```

Comment: This works but I wanted to also try find a way to generate the new id. The new object has id 6, because the last highest object id is 5. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So why isn't the `parent_id` 5 then instead of 4?

Comment: That is just the parent id. It just shows which parent it belongs to. The new object needs its own id and must be unique.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @NenadVracar I was hoping to try find a way to +1 the last id in the object tree.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a recursive function that would loop over each of the children until the id was found. One way of doing this could be:

```js
function findTeamById(id, tree) {
  if (id === tree.id) return tree //returning tree as it is the current team's object
  for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
    let teamTree = findTeamById(id, tree[i])
    if (teamTree !== false) {
      // return the found tree
      return teamTree
    }
  }
  // if no tree was found return false
  return false
}
// EDIT: forgot to show how to add the child
const newTeam = {
  "id":6, // New id
  "name":"Music",
  "emoji":"",
  "parent_id":4, //this will be the parent id it belongs to
  "children":[

  ]
}

// this will push the new team to the childrens array of the newTeams parent
findTeamById(newTeam.parent_id, myTree).children.push(newTeam)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'll need a recursive function to find the max ID, then get the parent of that maxID object and put the new object in its children.

```js
const tree = {"id":1,"name":"Rusty Corp.","emoji":"","parent_id":null,"children":[{"id":2,"name":"Food","emoji":"","parent_id":1,"children":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Canine Therapy","emoji":"","parent_id":1,"children":[{"id":4,"name":"Massages","emoji":"","parent_id":3,"children":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Games","emoji":"","parent_id":3,"children":[]}]}]};


const newObj = {
  "id": 6,
  "name": "Music",
  "emoji": "",
  "parent_id": 0,
  "children": []
}

var maxID=0;
var parentObj = null; 
function findMaxIDArray(obj) {
  var tmpid = maxID;
  maxID = Math.max(obj.id, maxID);
  if (maxID>tmpid) {
      parentObj = obj;
  }
  if (obj.children) {
    for(let c=0;c<obj.children.length;c++){
      if (obj.children[c]) {
         findMaxIDArray(obj.children[c]);
      }
    }
  }  
}



findMaxIDArray(tree);

if (parentObj) {
  newObj.parent_id=parentObj.id;
  parentObj.children.push(newObj);
}

console.log(tree);
```